# Is it possible to access stream data from Spotify?

Tags: spotify

I'm looking to build an app that streams music from spotify and manipulates the tempo and pitch of songs.

Is it possible to access the raw audio buffers from the Spotify iOS SDK, or from any other resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, raw audio is not accessible through any Spotify API/SDK. (PS, I highly recommend you read the [Developer Terms of Service](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/terms/))

Comment: Thanks for following up. I was referred to another Spotify library - https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify which was supposed to give me access to the raw audio buffer data. 

Barring the terms of service, is this a valid option to manipulate the audio streams with?

Comment: Libspotify was deprecated several years ago and should not be used in any new apps as it is not supported, App Keys are no longer issued, and may be turned off at any time.